# Why i got 0 answer when i tried to make 1 mistake all the scores

Tags: command-line, scripts, zsh

```
#!/bin/zsh
echo "enter quiz1 score:"
read quiz1
echo "enter quiz2 score:"
read quiz2
echo "enter seatwork score:"
read seatwork
echo "enter exam score:"
read exam
echo "enter lab1 score:"
read lab1
echo "enter lab2 score:"
read lab2
echo "enter lab3 score:"
read lab3

quiz1total=$((quiz1/20))
quiz2total=$((quiz2/30))
quiztotal=$(($quiz1total+$quiz2total))
quizaverage=$(($quiztotal*.20))
examtotal=$(($exam/50))
examaverage=$(($examtotal*.40))
seatworktotal=$((%seatwork/20))
seatworkaverage=$((seatworktotal*.20))
labtotal=$(($lab1+$lab2+$lab3))
labtotals=$(($labtotal/300))
labaverage=$(($labtotals*.20))
midterm=$(($quizaverage+$examaverage+$seatworkaverage+$labaverage))
midtermgrade=$(($midterm*100)
echo "your midterm grade is: $midtermgrade"
```

Comment: quiz1 total score is 20
quiz2 total score is 30
exam total score is 50
seatwork total score is 20
midterm grade = average quiz 20% seatwork 20% exam 40% lab 20%

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read [ask]. Debugging questions are better suited to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), but either way, please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

zsh treats `/` as integer division. Use `.` to indicate floating point numbers (for example, in `quiz1total=$((quiz1/20))` do `quiz1total=$((quiz1/20.))` instead).

```
$ echo $((1/20))
0
$ echo $((1./20))
0.050000000000000003
```